# integer argument expected, got float (when writing sine)

Tags: python, integer, spyder

I don't know how to solve the mistake and make it valid for floats. I want to draw a sinusoidal function in an image but when I do it writing `int(math.sin(n))` instead of `math.sin(n)` I only draw a line, not a curve. This is what I wrote:

```
import math

from PIL import Image

j = Image.new("RGB", (200, 100), (0, 80, 200))

def sin(j, color):
    w, h = j.size
    for x in range(w):
        n = math.pi 
        j.putpixel((x, (math.sin(n))), color)

sin(j, (200, 0, 0))
```

Comment: of course it is a line ... math.sin(n) is a constant since n is a constant ... it does not depend on your variable x

Comment: you are always calculating the `sin` of pi.

Comment: Even if `n` wasn't a constant, `int(math.sin(n))` would almost always be zero due to the conversion to int.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. How can I make a sinusoidal function ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not changing your input, so the result is always the same:

```
n = math.pi 
j.putpixel((x, (math.sin(n))), color)
```